# Connection between Matlab Server and Android Client

Tags: android, sockets, matlab, connection

I am trying to establish a reliable connection between a matlab running on PC
and an Android device (Galaxy tab)

My client code is based on the great example in this [link](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html).
In this example the server is a java app running on the pc.
I ran the example with the java app and it works perfectly.

My matlab code is based on a code I found in Mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab): 
(my code is posted below)

Unfortunately, the behaviour is very inconsistent, More often than not, there is no
connection at all. (Sometimes it **Does** work but only one word is sent)

I don't understand how the server side works,
Is the code line 'ServerConnect' a blocking one?
Does it have to synchronize with the client?

Thanks in advance!

Ariel

Here is my matlab code:

This is the main program:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.io.*

MessageStr = {'THIS','IS','MY','MESSAGE'};

server_socket  = ServerConnect(4444,inf);

output_socket = server_socket.accept;

for k = 1:length(MessageStr)

pause(3);  
ServerSend(MessageStr{k},server_socket,output_socket); 


end


%clean

close(server_socket);
```

This is the code for the function ServerConnect

```
function server_socket  = ServerConnect(output_port, number_of_retries)
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.io.*


retry             = 0;

server_socket  = [];
fprintf(1, 'waiting for client to connect\n');
while true

    retry = retry + 1;

    try
        if ((number_of_retries > 0) && (retry > number_of_retries))
            fprintf(1, 'Too many retries\n');
            break;
        end

        %fprintf(1, ['Try %d waiting for client to connect to this ' ...
        %            'host on port : %d\n'], retry, output_port);

        % wait for 1 second for client to connect server socket

        server_socket = ServerSocket(output_port);
        server_socket.setSoTimeout(1000);


        fprintf(1, 'Client connected\n');

        break;

    catch
        if ~isempty(server_socket)
            server_socket.close
        end


        % pause before retrying
        pause(1);
    end
end



end
```

And the code for server send:

```
function ServerSend(message,server_socket,output_socket);

import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.io.*

try



output_stream   = output_socket.getOutputStream;
d_output_stream = DataOutputStream(output_stream);

% output the data over the DataOutputStream
% Convert to stream of bytes
fprintf(1, 'Writing %d bytes\n', length(message))

d_output_stream.writeBytes(char(message));
d_output_stream.flush;


catch


end


end
```